# How can I make this simple form run properly?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get this script in php to work but it doesn't want to:

```
<body>
<FORM ACTION="second.php" METHOD="post">
YourName:
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="YourName"><BR />
CostOfLunch:
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="CostOfLunch"><BR />
DaysBuyingLunch:
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="DaysBuyingLunch"><BR />
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="x" VALUE="Calculate">
</FORM>
</body>
```

And the second file.

```
<body>
<?php $Today = date("l F d. Y"); ?>
   Today's Date: 
   <?php 
   /* 
   ** show today's date
   */
   print("<H3>$Today</H3>");     
   /*
   ** show information about cost of lunch
   */
   print("$YourName, this week, you will spend ");
   print($CostOfLunch * $DaysBuyingLunch);
   print(" dollars for lunch.<BR />\n");
?>
</body>
```

I'm testing these files in two ways:

1. By running `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 first.php` this command in cmd. And then navigating to adress bar in browser. I'm typing there `http://localhost:8000/`.
   In this way the page doesn't output the `second.php` but shows first page and clears the forms. It changes to `http://localhost:8000/second.php` though.
2. By typing `http://localhost:portnumber/first.php` in the adress bar. This works somewhat better cause I have installed *the Appache HTTP Server*. It navigates to `http://localhost:port/second.php` and changes the output of the site to the content of a file. Alas like this: `Today's Date:
   , this week, you will spend 0 dollars for lunch.` without running any script.

EDIT: Changing script to use echo and `$_POST` instead of `print()` like this `<?php echo $_POST['yourName']; ?>` have worked.
But only when using APACHE. When using built-in web server site content is not changing just clearing.

Comment: Important: do not use uppercase in your HTML tags or attribute names. Not just bad form, sometimes it'll bite you.

Comment: Also, your usage of PHP short tags is probably causing your PHP to not be processed

Comment: All of the form variables would be in the `$_POST` array. Like `$_POST['YourName']`

Comment: I'm learning from somewhat old book and I'm writing what there is written though.

Comment: @Saian that's your problem. You have access to the Internet, learn PHP the right way: https://phptherightway.com/

Comment: I'd hope to see at least the date between the h3 tags.  Which suggests to me, that your php is not being parsed.

Comment: This code *appears* to rely on the long-dead [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) functionality...

Comment: It seems like you found a PHP3/4 tutorial maybe in a book or something. If so, consider it garbage. So much has changed since then, in HTML and in PHP. Go to MDN and PHP.net for up-to-date code examples.

Comment: on the HTML side, also please read up on how to do HTML5 properly, ideally using one of any free code editors that come with linting and hinting plugins (sumblime text, VS Code, etc). You HTLM is not well-formatted at the moment (what on earth is a `</br>` for instance. Why would modern HTML even need `<br>` except inside plain text content. It should never be used between elements, that's what CSS is for)

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: OP has just been overloaded with information...

Comment: @gibberish, I thought tags and attribute names were case insensitive: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity

Comment: @gibberish, gibberish.

Comment: Yea, I need to if these $POST_ arrays will work.

Comment: Also missing `html` and `head` tags which are required and some browsers won't allow a working form without.

Comment: Can I check if parsing works some other way? @Progrock

Comment: @Progrock I don't know why but the date now always work even before changes.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be working from a **very** old, out of date, and dangerous PHP tutorial.

- `php -S` isn't running your PHP because you are using [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Don't use them, use `<?php ... ?>` instead.
- Your submitted form data is not showing up because you are depending on [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) instead of using the [`$_POST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Aside:

- This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!. Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Changing short tags to `<?php ... ?>` doesn't works either.

Comment: Also missing `html` and `head` tags which are required and some browsers won't allow a working form without.

Comment: I will check this in the moment. `html` and `head` tags are there.

Comment: So I think when following this book I should educate myself on `print()` and `$_POST` and use in the meantime `echo` command.